# Since there can only be one owner in Rust, does that mean shallow copies aren't possible?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm trying to understand the ownership model.  Since there can only be one owner in Rust, does that mean shallow copies aren't possible?  Is there something that is similar to a shallow copy?  I'm guessing you could do something with references, but that would force you to use a different type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rust uses distinct types to represent different degrees of ownership (single ownership, shared ownership or borrowed). Making a shallow copy implies that the copy will *share* some data with the original. This means that we must use types *that support sharing*.

One way to make a shallow copy is by copying shared references. For example, consider this program:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Greetings<'a> {
    hello: &'a str,
    goodbye: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
    let greetings = Greetings {
        hello: "Hello!",
        goodbye: "Goodbye!",
    };
    let new_greetings = greetings.clone();
    println!("{:?}", new_greetings);
}
```

When we clone `greetings`, we don't actually clone the strings; we only "clone" the references (which are just pointers). The compiler uses the lifetime parameter on `Greetings` to ensure that instances of `Greetings` don't outlive the strings stored inside them.

Another way to make a shallow copy is by storing an owned object in a `Rc` or `Arc` smart pointer and cloning that pointer. For example:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Greetings {
    hello: Rc<String>,
    goodbye: Rc<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let greetings = Greetings {
        hello: Rc::new("Hello!".into()),
        goodbye: Rc::new("Goodbye!".into()),
    };
    let new_greetings = greetings.clone();
    println!("{:?}", new_greetings);
}
```

When we clone `greetings`, the `Rc` objects are also cloned. When an `Rc` is cloned, the reference counter is incremented, but the object managed by the `Rc` is not cloned; rather, both the original and the cloned `Rc` objects refer to the same `String` object.